# ¿Existe algún atributo para HTML o PHP que al abrir un enlace cierre la pagina anterior?

Tags: php, html

Mi duda es que si al darle click a un enlace que este en una página, este mismo cierre la pagina origen al abrir la nueva página.

Answer (score 4):

Si añades `target="_self"` el enlace se abre en la misma ventana/pestaña dejando atrás el contenido anterior.

Si quieres abrir una ventana nueva (`"_blank"`) y cerrar la ventana anterior desde donde se abrió, lo puedes hacer con JavaScript `window.close().`

Ejemplo:

El JavaScript:

```
function cerrar_ventana() {
  window.close();
}
```

El HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.nuevaventana.com" onclick="cerrar_ventana();return false;" target="_blank">Cerrar</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

**[Ver demo para abrir y cerrar Tab del navegador](http://browserstrangeness.bitbucket.org/window_close_tester.htm)**

Solo puedes **cerrar** la `ventana` / `tab` con [window.close()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/close), si lo **abres** con [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/open).

Como dice la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/close#Description):

> *window.close()* solo se permite ser llamado por ventanas que fueron
>   abiertas por un script utilizando el método window.open(). Si la
>   ventana no fue abierta por un script, el siguiente error aparece en la
>   consola de JavaScript: Scripts may not close windows that were not
>   opened by script.

Para abrir `Tab` o `Ventana`:

```
<!-- abrir nuevo tab -->

<a href="" onclick="return open_new_tab();">Abrir nuevo Tab</a>

<script>
    function open_new_tab() {

        window.open('/example2.html', '_blank');

        return false;
    }
</script>


<!-- abrir nueva ventana -->

<a href="" onclick="return open_new_window();">Abrir nuevo Window</a>

<script>
    function open_new_window() {

        window.open('http://example.com/example2.html', '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Para cerrar cualquier de los dos nuevo `Tab` o `Ventana`:

```
<a href="" onclick="return close_tab_window();">Cerrar Tab/Ventana</a>

<script>
    function close_tab_window() {

        open('/example2.html', '_target').close();

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comprobado en (MAC OS):

- Chrome 53
- FireFox 49
- Safari 10